How to import the California housing dataset in an IDE like google colab
I tried importing the California housing dataset in my Kaggle and google colab notebook but I got an HTTPError. However this code works well on my Jupyter notebook
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
housing = fetch_california_housing()


I wonder if here would help you work around this. As for the issue, I see it, too with Google Colab, while it works in vanilla Jupyter; however, I don't use Colab enough to know if usual or not. Here and here suggest it happens from time to time on networks.

I opened another Google Colab notebook (this one) as I was writing my last comment, and now it works. I was then thinking Google was having a hiccup or it varies by where you are in their system or zones/regions?  However, the fact a new session from this link with the same code fails (consistently?) making me think it is something else. ...

 %pip list from each looks similar to me (similar because I didn't check everything for the long list but what I looked at was same) and !jupyter --version gives identical results.
